# entity framework enable-migrations no context type was found in the assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I know this question has already been answered before, but it's still not working for me. I am learning ASP.NET and Entity Framework for the very first time and I am trying to enable migrations

This is my project structure

[image]

`Models/DatabaseContext.cs`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FileManager.Models
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
            modelBuilder.Entity<File>().ToTable("File");
        }

    }
}
```

Those are the commands I run in package manager :

`Enable-Migrations`

`Enable-Migrations -ProjectName FileManager -StartupProject FileManager`

Both of them are giving me this error : No context type was found in the assembly 'FileManager'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like this **Enable-Migrations -Context DatabaseContext -Project FileManager** or **Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName DatabaseContext -Project FileManager**